# Does Source of SVN Externals Has To Be A Repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I'm trying to set up a svn externals on my local Windows machine with TortoiseSVN. I created a working directory by selecting `SVN Checkout`. It contains a directory named `lib` whose contents should be imported from an external location. I followed [this tutorial](http://justaddwater.dk/2007/10/23/setting-up-subversion-externals-with-tortoisesvn/) and [this](http://troyworks.com/blog/2009/08/19/svn-externals-how-to-use-multiple-svns-in-one-using-tortoisesvn/) but still am having hard time setting it up.

The current structure looks like this:

> /myproject/trunk/core.php
>
> /myproject/trunk/lib/
>
> /myanotherproject/trunk/core.php
>
> /myanotherproject/trunk/lib/lib01.php

I'd like to make it automatically import the lib files of `myproject` from the `myanotherproject` directory. The `myanotherproject` directory is not a repository. It is also a working directory of another project.

What I did:

1. Right Clicked on he `myproject/trunk/lib` folder and chose `TortoiseSVN -> Properties`
2. Selected `New -> Externals`
3. Clicked on the `New` button and in the URL field typed, `file:///Z:/myanotherproject/trunk/lib`
4. Clicked `OK`

Then I got the error:

> Error parsing svn:externals property on
> 'Z:\myproject\trunk\lib':
> 'file:///Z:/myanotherproject/trunk/lib'

So does the import source have to be a repository since the URL has to be specified? Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a working copy as the source for `svn:externals` and I don't really understand why you need that.

`svn:externals` has to point to **a repository location**; you can point to a different repository BTW. In some cases you may want to specify a revision number of the `svn:externals` source.

I advise you to check the [`svn:externals` reference in the SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html). The first two sentences answer your question:

> Sometimes it is useful to construct a working copy that is made out of
>   a number of different checkouts. For example, you may want **different
>   subdirectories to come from different locations in a repository or
>   perhaps from different repositories altogether**.

Please also check the [TortoiseSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) on this topic.

Comment: `I don't really understand why you need that.` - I intended the `myanotherproject` folder is for a published/public project and the `myproject` folder is for a local project. So I thought I could import the public project locally. I tried setting the URL to the public url which `myanotherproject` is using and it accepted without an error. So it seems to be working. I got another issue though which the imported files do not update. But this is a different issue so I'll ask another question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: "it's strongly recommended to specify a revision number" - Using PEG-revision is strictly user-choice and style-dependent

Comment: @LazyBadger I agree. Thank you for noting the misleading statement. I've just reworded it.

Answer (score 2):

Follow-up to @bahrep

External must use Repo-path URL, not WC-URL, because from WC of "superproject" you'll be able

- checkout
- update
- and even commit

with the externals, which is impossible for Working Copy, only for repository